# DAX formula COUNT based on Measure

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, measure

[image]Is it possible to create a measure that counts the values of another measure? In the data set attached, I would like to count how many times each person has a value >= .2 in the last week. But that value (.2) is generated by a measure. Can it be counted by another measure?

with the data set below, the answer should be: Person A = 3 and Person B = 2

This is what I tried:

Count of Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Data Data'[Name]),[Measure Value] >= .2,DATESINPERIOD('Data'[Date],LASTDATE('Data'[Date]),-5,DAY))

I am struggling heavily to use Count or Count Distinct and get the "last week" filter.